# PyQt5 User Checkable QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I want to create a Table using a SQLite database. In the table user can select maximum 5 item. We will evaluate those items in another page.

Current status: I have created a table using Qt Designer. I have fetched the SQL data into table. While inserting the Name column in table I have used:

item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

Now, I have checkbox beside every name. But I cannot understand how can I process the user selection. I tried using "itemClicked" but it cannot determine which item is clicked.

Does someone have any idea how can I index my items and respective checkboxes so that I can fetch the specific rows which user has selected?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'dbTable.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
import sys

import sqlite3



from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem



class Ui_MainWindow(QWidget):

    def message(self):

        print("selected")



    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 130, 580, 650))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(20)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 40, 131, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.showMaximized()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        # this is the method for selecting data


        mydb = sqlite3.connect("ppcp_database.db")

        mycursor = mydb.cursor()

        mycursor.execute("SELECT ALL Name FROM Table1")


        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(20)
        rowIndex_col0 = 0
        rowIndex_col1 = 0
        rowIndex_col2 = 0
        rowIndex_col3 = 0
        rowIndex_col4 = 0



        for row in mycursor.execute("SELECT ALL Name FROM Table1"):

            item = QTableWidgetItem(row[0])
            item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
                          QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowIndex_col0, 0, item)





            rowIndex_col0+=1

        self.tableWidget.itemClicked.connect(self.message)







        for row in mycursor.execute("SELECT ALL Solubility FROM Table2"):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowIndex_col1, 1, QTableWidgetItem(row[0]))
            rowIndex_col1+=1

        for row in mycursor.execute("SELECT ALL Volatility FROM Table2"):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowIndex_col2, 2, QTableWidgetItem(row[0]))
            rowIndex_col2+=1

        for row in mycursor.execute("SELECT ALL Adsorbability FROM Table2"):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowIndex_col3, 3, QTableWidgetItem(row[0]))
            rowIndex_col3+=1

        for row in mycursor.execute("SELECT ALL Degradability FROM Table2"):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rowIndex_col4, 4, QTableWidgetItem(row[0]))
            rowIndex_col4+=1

            

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Evaluate"))





if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Connect the table with the [`itemChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged) signal, which returns a QTableWidgetItem, on which you can verify its [`checkState()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#checkState). Please, consider that the warning at the beginning of that file should *not* be underestimated: manually modifiying files created with pyuic is considered *bad* practice, as almost always leads to bugs and unexpected behavior. Read more on the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: You can inherit from QSqlTableModel (or use composition) and override `flags` to return `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` with default flags for first column and `data()` method for `Qt.CheckStateRole` role to return either Qt.Checked or Qt.Unchecked and `setData` method to modify checked state

Comment: I have solved the problem with the help of your suggestions. Thanks. But I have one new problem.

User can select boxes. I have used following code:

self.view.clicked.connect(self.message)

but as I have used clicked, so even if user uncheck the box, i am getting connected. 


Can someone help me to introduce a boolean condition before clicked?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
class TableModel(QSqlTableModel):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    QSqlTableModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.checkeable_data = {}

def flags(self, index):
    fl = QSqlTableModel.flags(self, index)
    if index.column() == 0:
        fl |= Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
    return fl

def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role == Qt.CheckStateRole and (
        self.flags(index) & Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable != Qt.NoItemFlags
    ):
        i
f index.row() not in self.checkeable_data.keys():
            self.setData(index, Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        return self.checkeable_data[index.row()]
    else:
        return QSqlTableModel.data(self, index, role)

def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
    if role == Qt.CheckStateRole and (
        self.flags(index) & Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable != Qt.NoItemFlags
     ):
        self.checkeable_data[index.row()] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, (role,))
        return True
    return QSqlTableModel.setData(self, index, value, role)
```

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc, could you help me manipulating with the above answer? I want to do two things:
1. User cannot edit the table.
2. User can edit and save the new entry. 

I guess I have to use setEditStrategy. But how can I add this feature with the existing code? TIA.